# How to determine the number of free bytes on a disk in Windows 10 on the terminal without elevation?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, disk-space

If I run this command:

> fsutil volume diskfree e:

I get:

> Error:  Access is denied.

Only by manually opening an "elevated" cmd.exe does it output the actual output of the command.

I need a (built-in) command which determines the free space of a given disk (drive letter), even if the cmd.exe is not "elevated" (administrator).

(The reason it requires elevation is apparently that "fsutil" can do a bunch of other things as well.)

Comment: `dir e:` will output the number of free bytes.

Comment: Minor note: the system folder `WinSxS` contains symlinks (or similar) so those files are often counted multiple times by windows and this can cause a lower free-space count than is actually present. I don't think there is a work-around for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is along the same lines as @It Wasn't Me's answer

If you just want to see a quick output this is generally fastest:

```cmd
DIR /AD/D E: | FIND /I " bytes free"

--[Result]--
               1 Dir(s)  28,616,892,416 bytes free
```

`DIR /AD` Will only return directories, `/D` is wide, meaning many entries are returned on each line.  If you have a massive number of directories and only a few files change it to `DIR /A-D/D`

I don't see why you would need to get rid of the formatting of this output considering `FSUtil` offers a bunch of extra text and it wasn't mentioned in the question, also It includes the commas.

If you do want to remove the Commas as mention `/-C` will remove commas.

If you want the number out by itself to be used whether with or without commas the `for /f` loop becomes necessary, which @It Wasn't Me's has already covered well.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use cmd internal command `dir` with `/e` and `/-c` to remove `,` from outputs

```
17 Dir(s)  21,489,500,160 bytes free
```

**2.** Using the 3rd token in `for /f` loop redirect to `findstr /End` filter where the line ends with "bytes" + [one character] + "free"

```
1º   2º        3º               *º
_| _____|  __________| __________*
17 Dir(s)  21489500160 bytes free  
tokens  =      3º     |----------| is the same bytes.free to findstr
```

---

- For command line:

```
for /f "tokens=3delims= " %i in ('dir E: /d /-c ^|findstr /e bytes.free')do @echo\%i
```

---

- For bat file replace `%i` to `%%i`:

```
@echo off 

for /f "tokens=3delims= " %%i in ('dir E: /d /-c ^|findstr /e bytes.free')do echo\%%i
```

---

- You can get some help from PowerShell to convert the free size to GB:

```
@echo off 

for /f "tokens=3delims= " %i in ('dir E: /d /-c ^|findstr /e bytes.free
')do Powershell -nop -c "$free=[math]::round(8357258532/1GB); Write-host $free'GB' -NoNewline
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dir` you can do this (since Vista IIRC) with `wmic`:

```
 wmic volume where driveletter="E:" get freespace
 wmic volume get driveletter,freespace | findstr E:
```

Or if you use Powershell, it can do the whole job without help:

```
 powershell -c write-host (get-volume -driveletter c).sizeremaining
 powershell -c write-host [math]::round((get-volume -driveletter c).sizeremaining/1GB)
```